# K-Means clustering algorithm with dataset segmentations

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I know this is not how the algorithm suppose to work like but I have some constraints and limitation in my system and try to understand if it is applicable.

**My Question:**
k-means clustering algorithm requires whole dataset (observations) to work on for it clustering.
My question is there way to use k-means algorithm (or other algorithm) but in "iterative" way by revealing each time another part of the dataset (next segment) and keeping some "calculations" from previous runs.

**For example:**
Dividing the dataset into N parts and run the algorithm for k iterations on the first part and getting the result and somehow storing the results in good way so they will be used in the future.
After running the algorithm on all the parts take the stored results and use it (maybe by rerunning the algorithm on it) to give the final result.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here, please? A [mcve] would be appreciated. You could maybe use the centroids derived from the first data set as starting positions for the second set...

Comment: What you've mentioned with centroids is more or less what I'm trying to acheive, in any case I will add an example.

Comment: Yes that definitely sounds possible. You don't even need to re-implement everything yourself; the KMeans class in sklearn allows you to re-feed the cluster centres and to control the number of iterations: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans